# c++ static array sizeof()

Tags: c++, pointers, static-array

Here is some code:

```
int static_array[10];
cout<<"sizeof(static_array): " <<sizeof(static_array)<<endl;

int *ptr = static_array;
cout<<"sizeof(ptr): " <<sizeof(ptr)<<endl;
```

which outputs:

```
sizeof(static_array): 40
sizeof(ptr): 8
```

As far as I understand, in C++ arrays are pointers and the sizeof(ptr) function returns the size of the pointer. What I don't understand, if static_array is a pointer (which has to be, since I assigned it to ptr), why its size is actually 40 bytes (10 integers) instead of 8.

Comment: C++ arrays are not pointers. This is a common pitfall due to the fact that they decay to a pointer when passed as function arguments. But a static array and a pointer are completely different types. Therefore the difference in the result of the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: So when static_array is passed as a function argument to sizeof(), why doesn't it decay to a pointer?

Comment: Because `sizeof` is not a function it's an operator.